# get response from remote server using ip board

Tags: php, php-curl, ipb

i want to get data from remote API with curl but not works:
(im using ip board btw)

```
$url = "http://www.voobly.com/api/findusers/". $nick_list . "?key=" . $voobly_key;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

this is the response i get:

> Please enable cookies. One more step
>
> Please complete the security check to access www.voobly.com
>
> Why do I have to complete a CAPTCHA?
>
> Completing the CAPTCHA proves you are a human and gives you temporary
>   access to the web property.
>
> What can I do to prevent this in the future?
>
> If you are on a personal connection, like at home, you can run an
>   anti-virus scan on your device to make sure it is not infected with
>   malware.
>
> If you are at an office or shared network, you can ask the network
>   administrator to run a scan across the network looking for
>   misconfigured or infected devices.
>
> Cloudflare Ray ID: 3b009b3171e55c09 • Your IP: 69.89.31.238 •
>   Performance & security by Cloudflare

anyone know how to solve this

API provider said i need to add a valid browser agent string + PHP cookie session but idk what wrong here :(

Comment: What happens when you view the URL in a web browser?

Comment: it works perfectly :(

Answer (score 1):

The web site you're trying to access has misconfigured Cloudflare to block bots from accessing their site… including the API.

You will need to contact them to have them disable this. There is no easy workaround -- the whole point of this feature is to prevent scripts from accessing the site.

Comment: but i use the same api in another hosting/domain and it works very well. Tho in these i use file_get_contents function.

Comment: Agreed, this is a poorly developed API